# How to push() data in array in once

Tags: php, arrays, excel

```
if ($file_extension == "xlsx") {
    include("excel/PHPExcel.php");
    include("excel/Excel2007.php");
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
    foreach($sheetData as $row) {
        //// How to put all cells in array in one shot because we can not assign each like $row['A'] ,$row['B']
        array_push($array, strval($row['A']));
        //row A2;
        //array_push($array,strval($row['B']));
        //etc...
    }
}
```

How to put All Cells in an array without specifying name for each?

Because it's very difficult to write `$row['A']`, `$row['B']`, `$row['C']` ...... For Each.

How to put all data in an array without assigning names of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the arrays

```
$array = array_merge($array, $row);
```